# Keras multi-gpu batch normalization

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, batch-normalization

1) How does the batch normalization layer work with [multi_gpu_model](https://keras.io/utils/#multi_gpu_model)?

Is it calculated separately on each GPU, or is somehow synchronized between GPUs?

2) Which batch normalization parameters are saved when saving a model? (Since when using multiple-gpus in Keras, the original model must be saved, as suggested [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8446#issuecomment-343559454))?

In the docs of `multi_gpu_model` is says:

> Specifically, this function implements single-machine multi-GPU data
>   parallelism.

What does it mean for Batch Normalization?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) How does batch normalization layer work with multi_gpu_model?

For N GPUs, there are N copies of model, one on each GPU. For each copy, forward and backward passes are executed for a sub-batch (each sub-batch is 1/Nth of a batch). This means, batch normalization is actually sub-batch normalization, there is no access to the rest of batch.

```
# This `fit` call will be distributed on 8 GPUs.
# Since the batch size is 256, each GPU will process 32 samples.
parallel_model.fit(x, y, epochs=20, batch_size=256)
```

> 2) Which batch normalization parameters are saved when saving a model
>   (since when using multiple-gpus in Keras original model must be saved,
>   as suggested here)?

One unified (template) weight is saved instead of N different weights. Each GPU calculates a different gradient due to receiving a different sub-batch. Then, either (1) weights are updated separately on each GPU and become synchronized periodically, or (2) N outputs/gradients are aggregated on the template model (on CPU), and then new weights are broadcasted back to GPUs. In both cases, there is a unified (template) model, although in the first case, the template model may not always have the latest weights since it is kept out of synchronization and gets updated occasionally.

**Extra remarks**

1. [Some researchers](https://hangzhang.org/PyTorch-Encoding/notes/syncbn.html) have proposed a specific synchronizing technique for batch normalization to utilize the whole batch instead of a sub-batch. They state:

   > Standard Implementations of BN in public frameworks (suck as Caffe,
   >   MXNet, Torch, TF, PyTorch) are unsynchronized, which means that the
   >   data are normalized within each GPU.

   [image]
2. Because of weights synchronization [we cannot expect a linear speed-up](http://blog.datumbox.com/5-tips-for-multi-gpu-training-with-keras/) w.r.t. number of GPUs.
3. Some technicalities of `multi_gpu_model` are discussed in this [github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9204). `multi_gpu_model` has a speed gain when weights are sparse (in comparison to Dense layers), otherwise  weights synchronization becomes a bottleneck.
4. Also, here is an example of GPU-GPU weight synchronization flow from [Nvidia](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-cn/2018/pdf/CH8209.pdf):
   [image]

Comment: How do you know that Keras does weights synchronization since in the docs of multi_gpu_model function it only says that original model and the parallel model share weights (`# Save model via the template model (which shares the same weights)`) ?

Comment: @AntonioJurić you are right, that's an inaccurate statement, because if all N copies have the same weight *at all times*, what the `.fit` is doing on separate GPUs and separate data? So weights are different temporarily and become unified periodically.

Comment: @AntonioJurić I was wrong in my previous comment. They could have the same weights at all times. Updated.